# AsyncTask - OnPostExecute's result is null, I am completely lost as to why

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

In the `doInBackground` method, which returns an array of YouTube links, I log the value of the array right before returning it to make sure that it is not null. However, when I try to use it in the `onPostExecute` method (using the 'result' variable), I get a null array error. I cannot for the life of me find an explanation. Here's my code:

**doInBackground:**

```
@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

    // If there's no parameter, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
    if (params.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String rawJsonStr = null;
    try {
        // Construct the URL for the TMDb query
        //Define strings for creating the url:
        final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
        final String PARAM_API_KEY = "?api_key=----"; //REMEMBER NOT TO LEAVE YOUR KEYS HERE!
        final String TRAILER_REVIEWS_APPEND = "&append_to_response=trailers,reviews";

        URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + movieId + PARAM_API_KEY + TRAILER_REVIEWS_APPEND);

        // Create the request to TMDb, and open the connection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }
        rawJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
        return null;
    } finally{
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
    try{
        getMovieDataFromJson(rawJsonStr);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Before returning: " + getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr)[0]);
        return getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Coudn't return trailer array");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note: Yes, I'm using the necessary parameters when invoking the `AsyncTask`

**onPostExecute:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "After returning: " + result[0]);
     }
```

The app crashes, and on the logs, I get first an "attempted to read from null array" exception in the line that belongs to the onPostExecute method. Then, I get the correct "Before returning: YouTubeLink" log.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

getTrailerData method:

```
private String[] getTrailerDataFromJson(String rawJsonData)
            throws JSONException {

        final String TMDb_TRAILERS = "trailers";

        //Get the object corresponding to the movie
        JSONObject movieData = new JSONObject(rawJsonData);

        //Create trailer objects
        JSONObject trailerData = movieData.getJSONObject(TMDb_TRAILERS);
        JSONArray youtubeTrailers = trailerData.getJSONArray("youtube");
        String[] trailerLinks = new String[youtubeTrailers.length()];

        //Get trailers
        for (int i = 0; i < youtubeTrailers.length(); i++){
            if (!youtubeTrailers.isNull(i)){
                JSONObject trailer = youtubeTrailers.getJSONObject(i);
                trailerLinks[i] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + trailer.getString("source");
            }
            else{
                noTrailers = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return trailerLinks;
    }
```

The log error is the following:

```
08-13 14:30:54.422  17240-17240/com.mightybarbet.quickmovieinfo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mightybarbet.quickmovieinfo, PID: 17240
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
        at com.mightybarbet.quickmovieinfo.DetailActivityFragment$FetchMovieInfoTask.onPostExecute(DetailActivityFragment.java:258)
        at com.mightybarbet.quickmovieinfo.DetailActivityFragment$FetchMovieInfoTask.onPostExecute(DetailActivityFragment.java:105)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Sorry I took so long, my internet went out.

Line 105 is the declaring of the AsyncTask:

```
public class FetchMovieInfoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
```

And line 258 is the line inside onPostExecute:

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "After returning: " + result[0]);
```

Comment: There must be an exception in `getTrailerDataFromJson` - please share its code and also the logcat output that shows you were able to print `Before returning: ...`

Comment: That is because you are returning `null` in the `finally` block

Comment: please check my answer// @Bensas

Comment: @Bensas: Are you sure you are not returning `null` from `doInBackground`?

Comment: side note `Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary` that's not true. the newline can be in a string literal in the json, and can be part of the content. removing it would corrupt the content.

Comment: @BugsHappen you are right...

Comment: @WandMaker I just updated the post

Comment: Please, provide the activity/service/whatever that has the `getTrailerDataFromJson` method, as well as the Logcat. As far as this problem looks like, you are invoking a command in a View that is not active.

Comment: @Bensas Please, reffrain from swearing....  There is an error: `String[] trailerLinks = new String[youtubeTrailers.length()];` length is not a function, is a property, should be `String[youtubeTrailers.length]`

Comment: The method is in the AsyncTask, which is inside a fragment that belongs to an activity. Should I provide the fragment's code, the activity's code, or both?

Comment: I think you are better of using IDE's debugging capabilities as it is difficult to figure out from parts of code what is going wrong - your exception stack trace indicate that your onPostExecute has 100+ lines of code whereas you have shared few lines of code

Comment: @Bonatti youtubeTrailers is a JSON Array, so it's correct. the .length property doesn't exist in it.

Comment: are you sure that `rawJsonData` is in correct JSON formatting? You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: Yup this exact same code works in the main activity of the App, using the same API, but without using a return statement. On a different App, it works with a return statement, in the exact same format :/

Comment: @Bensas [From here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONArray%28int%29), I could only find `public JSONArray getJSONArray(int index)`. You are using `JSONArray youtubeTrailers = trailerData.getJSONArray("youtube");` a string...Please, check if this is not giving you issues.

Comment: @Bonatti I am able to get the URLs from the JSON data, so there isn't a problem with that.

Comment: @WandMaker Yes, my onPostExecute has more code than that, but I commented it all out and ran it again before posting here.

Comment: @Bensas Do the variable name `trailerLinks` appears outside of the scope of that funcion? [Could it be shadowed?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)... Also, please mark the lines `258` and `105` from `com.mightybarbet.quickmovieinfo.DetailActivityFragment$FetchMovieInfoTask.onPostExecute(DetailActivityFragment.java:258)` for us.

Comment: @Bonatti I just checked, and I'm not using that variable name anywhere outside of the getTrailerData function. I just updated the post with the lines.

Comment: in the postExecute method do it: super.onPostExecute();

Comment: @Bensas Just to rule out any scoping issues, try this:
Replace `return getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr);` With `String[] temp = getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr); return temp;` Finally, check if `(!youtubeTrailers.isNull(i))` actually returns false (log it)... if it does, that `trailerLinks[i]` is null... and would throw that error

Comment: @Bensas: Please check the JSON format, i think the problem is with its parsing

Comment: @Bonatti changing the return statement didn't help, and (!youtubeTrailers.isNull(i)) returned true as it should.

Comment: @Bonatti I'm sure the JSON is correct, I can get the youtube urls that I need and store them and log them without problem, the problem is after I've returned them. Could something be wrong with the internal code of AsyncTask?

Comment: @Bensas What I meant was, is there a condition where `trailerLinks[i]` remains un-initialized (and therefore null)? If it does, thats most likely where you are getting the NullPointerException... Also, from my experience with Java, you are having scope issues, as in the variable is not being replicated outside of the scope you are using it.

Comment: Guys! onPostExecute is being executed before AND after the doInBackground method!
I've no idea why, but that's why I get the null error. AsyncTask hasn't returned a result yet when onPostExecute is executed for the first time so the 'result' variable is null. I just created a global int variable and set it to 4. Inside doInBackground, I increased it by one and inside onPostExecute y logged it. When I run the program, it logs 4, then a url that I logged from doInBackground, and then 5.

Comment: @Bonatti Yes there is, but I'm making sure to pick a movie that I know has trailer info available, and I'm logging the trailer URLs that I get just for good measure. What do you mean by the variable not being replicated? I define it right before the for loop and log it's content right after it without problem,  then return it. there are no global variables interfering if that's what you mean. Look at my last comment though, I believe that's where the problem lies, though I have no idea how to procede.

Comment: Yup, when I use the debugger and insert a stop in onPostExecute and another in the doInBackground, the program stops three times 
(onPostExecute --> doInBackground -->onPostExecute).

Comment: @Bensas: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse, Android Studio, or other? Also, please keep your Android SDK up-to-date, if its not.

Comment: How are you calling the `AsyncTask`? The order should be `onPreExecute()`, -> `doInBackground()` -> `onProgressUpdate()` then when completed, `onPostExecute()` .... can you post the full asynctask class, then the places where you are executing it? It could either be misspelling of functions, or that you are executing it more than once at the same time.

Comment: In the end I added an "if (result != null){}" statement inside the onPostExecute method, so that what's in it is only executed after doInBackground has finished. As to why onPostExecute is being called before AND after doInBackground, I have no idea. Thanks a bunch for the help guys!

Answer (score -1):

Replace your method and look at the final log "final return trailer array"

```
  @Override
  protected String[] doInBackground(String... params)
  {

  // If there's no parameter, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
   if (params.length == 0) {
    return null;
   }
   // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
   // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
   BufferedReader reader = null;
   // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
   String rawJsonStr = null;
   String[] resultArray = null;
   try {
    // Construct the URL for the TMDb query
    //Define strings for creating the url:
    final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    final String PARAM_API_KEY = "?api_key=----"; //REMEMBER NOT TO   LEAVE YOUR KEYS HERE!
    final String TRAILER_REVIEWS_APPEND = "&append_to_response=trailers,reviews";

    URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + movieId + PARAM_API_KEY + TRAILER_REVIEWS_APPEND);

    // Create the request to TMDb, and open the connection
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.connect();

    // Read the input stream into a String
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (inputStream == null) {
        // Nothing to do.
        return null;
    }
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
        // buffer for debugging.
        buffer.append(line + "\n");
    }

    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
        return null;
    }
    rawJsonStr = buffer.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
    return null;
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
        }
    }
   }
   try{
    getMovieDataFromJson(rawJsonStr);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Before returning: " + getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr)[0]);
    resultArray =  getTrailerDataFromJson(rawJsonStr);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't return trailer array");
  }
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "final return trailer array"+resultArray;);
  return resultArray;
}
```